# netbeans not making fxml controllor when i click "make controller" after saving fxml file

Tags: java-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I am using netbeans 12 with jdk 1.8 (I can't update because of compatability issues) for a javafx application. After I save my fxml file and click "make controller" nothing happens.